# How to secure your data using .env?

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, gatsby

For my project I was using Contentful CMS and Gatsby, I've tried to put keys into .env file, but I am getting "keys are not defined".

Here is the code for gatsby-config.js:

```js
plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-contentful',
      options: {
        spaceId: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID, 
        accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN
      }
    }....
```

Here I am providing the "keys", however, I am getting this issue:

```js
 ERROR 

Problems with gatsby-source-contentful plugin options:
spaceId: undefined - "spaceId" is required
accessToken: undefined - "accessToken" is required
host (default value): "cdn.contentful.com"
environment (default value): "master"
downloadLocal (default value): false
localeFilter (default value): [Function]
forceFullSync (default value): false
pageLimit (default value): 100
useNameForId (default value): true

not finished onPreInit - 0.026s
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gatsby-starter-hello-world@0.1.0 develop: `gatsby develop`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-starter-hello-world@0.1.0 develop script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gatsby-starter-hello-world@0.1.0 start: `npm run develop`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-starter-hello-world@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\debug.log
```

Thanks for stopping by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with [environment variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/environment-variables/), you have to point to the file where the variables are stored.

By default Gatsby supports 2 environments:

- Development. If you run `gatsby develop`, then you will be in the "development" environment.
- Production. If you run `gatsby build` or `gatsby serve`, then you will be in the "production" environment.

In your case, besides adding the following snippet in your `gatsby-config.js` (above the exportation) you just need to create a `.env.development` and .`env.production` in the root of your project.

```
require(`dotenv`).config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
});


module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
  // your metadata
  },
  plugins: [
  // your plugins
  ],
}
```

Then, in your `.env.development`/`.env.production`:

```
CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID= "yourSpaceId"
CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN= "yourAccesToken"
```

You can customize this behavior to change the environment file where the variables are stored if needed.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have created .env.development file and added CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID... into that file. But, where should I put require("dotenv")...code that you have mentioned ?

Comment: Now I'm getting this issue:   Error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object

Comment: There was a mistake in my snippet. Replace the `:` for `=` in the environment files. Check it out, it's updated.